# QueryExpression: How to compare the column values of linked entities?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

Dynamics 365.

QueryExpression: How to compare the column values of linked entities?

```
var query1 = new QueryExpression("entity1");
query1.ColumnSet.AddColumns("userid");  
var link1 = query1.AddLink("entity2", "entity2id", "entity2Id", JoinOperator.Inner);
link1.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("ownerId", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 
true, "entity1.userid"); // Here is problem!
```

Comment: uhm, never tried on linked entities, did you try to specify an EntityAlias for the linked entity and swap the fields inside the criteria? honestly I don't know if it's possible at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. It is only possible to compare columns that reside in the same the table/record.

E.g. using this example:

```cs
var query = new QueryExpression("account");
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("createdon", ConditionOperator.Equal, true, "modifiedon"));
```

...you could query alle accounts that have never been modified. The `true` parameter in the constructor of the `ConditionExpression` simply tells the query processor to interpret the value part as a column name. However, you cannot specify the entity name as well.

See [MS Docs - Use column comparison in queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/column-comparison#limitations).